# $log anonymous function angular js not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, anonymous-function, webtorrent

I have a problem when I try to log some data inside the function of webtorrent.

I want to log some values of **this.client.add** but I don't have access.

Some idea of what's going on here?

```
    import Webtorrent from 'webtorrent';

    class PlaylistController {
      /** @ngInject */
      constructor($http, $log) {
        this.log = $log;
        this.client = new Webtorrent();

        $http
          .get('app/playlist/playlist.json')
          .then(response => {
            this.Torrent = response.data;
          });
      }

      addTorrent(magnetUri) {
        this.log.log(magnetUri);

        this.client.add(magnetUri, function (torrent) {
          // Got torrent metadata!
          this.log.log('Client is downloading:', torrent.infoHash);

          torrent.files.forEach(file => {
            this.log(file);
          });
        });
        this.log.log('sda');
        this.log.log(this.client);
      }
    }

    export const playlist = {
      templateUrl: "app/playlist/playlist.html",
      controller: PlaylistController,
      bindings: {
        playlist: '<'
      }
    };
```

[image: Here is the output of the console]

Another thing its I use yeoman for the scaffold of my app and its has JSLint with `console.log` forbidden and its said that you must use `angular.$log`, but the thing its I don't wanna change that, I wanna understand the problem here.

Comment: add `/*eslint no-console: ["error", { allow: ["warn", "error"] }] */` at very first line in your JS file to remove `console.log()` warning. [Reference](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console)

Comment: Yes, thats other solution, but i want to understand why i cannot use $log in the function.

Comment: You are using `this` inside function (torrent) { ... } which would refer to that function and not the class (which is the one you want to refer to). In pure ES6, you could use arrow function instead of a normal one so that the this reference remains the outer one.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to refer to this (the class) as another variable to use inside the function(torrent) function or use arrow functions so that this reference remains the class one.

Solution 1, using another variable to ref the class:

```
addTorrent(magnetUri) {
    this.log.log(magnetUri);

    var that = this;

    this.client.add(magnetUri, function (torrent) {
      // Got torrent metadata!
      that.log.log('Client is downloading:', torrent.infoHash);

      torrent.files.forEach(file => {
        that.log(file);
      });
    });
    this.log.log('sda');
    this.log.log(this.client);
  }
```

Solution 2, using arrow functions:

```
addTorrent(magnetUri) {
    this.log.log(magnetUri);

    this.client.add(magnetUri, torrent => {
      // Got torrent metadata!
      this.log.log('Client is downloading:', torrent.infoHash);

      torrent.files.forEach(file => {
        this.log(file);
      });
    });
    this.log.log('sda');
    this.log.log(this.client);
  }
```